# Polymer neon-animation : Can I animate multiple nodes with one animation?

Tags: polymer-1.0

Regarding Neon Animations ( https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/using-neon-animations )

Is it possible to specify the same animation to run simultaneously on multiple nodes?
For example:

```
   animationConfig: {
     value: function() {
       return {
         'entry': {
           name: 'bounce-in-animation',
           node: Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("div"),  // here
           timing: {duration: 1000}
         },
         'exit': {
           name: 'fade-out-animation',
           node: this
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

In the above code sample (specifically in "//here"), I’m attempting to run ‘bounce-in-animation’ on multiple div instances instead of just one.
Is this presently possible?

I tried the code above, and got a 'Cannot execute' type of error.  So I'm really asking if there is a way to achieve what the code above intends.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `cascaded-animation` and in your `entry` definition use:

```
{
  name: 'cascaded-animation',
  animation: 'bounce-in-animation',
  nodes: Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("div"),
  nodeDelay: 0, // You can use this to delay animation between each node
  timing: {duration: 1000}
}
```

Here you have a quick demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Polymer cascaded animation</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.7.22/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://polygit.org/components/neon-animation/neon-animation-runner-behavior.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://polygit.org/components/neon-animation/animations/fade-in-animation.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://polygit.org/components/neon-animation/animations/cascaded-animation.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>
  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div>
        Hi! I'm a div!
      </div>
      <div>
        Hello! I'm another div!
      </div>
      <div>
        And I'm the last div!
      </div>
      <button on-tap="runAnimation">Click me!</button>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          behaviors: [
            Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
          ],
          properties: {
            animationConfig: {
              value: function() { return {
                'entry': {
                  name: 'cascaded-animation',
                  animation: 'fade-in-animation',
                  nodes: Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("div"),
                  nodeDelay: 0, // You can use this to delay animation between each node
                  timing: {duration: 1000}
                }
              } }
            }
          },
          runAnimation: function() {
            this.playAnimation('entry')
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: If you are confused about imports - import from `bower_components`, I had to import from those sources to make the demo work.

**EDIT2**: After reading your comment I have another idea: you can tell Polymer that every time the elements is initialized you want it to check all of the divs in it and register animation for this one. I'm not best at describing but maybe the demo will help you understand it better:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Polymer cascaded animation</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.7.22/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://polygit.org/components/neon-animation/neon-animation-runner-behavior.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://polygit.org/components/neon-animation/animations/fade-in-animation.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://polygit.org/components/neon-animation/animations/cascaded-animation.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>
  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div>
        Hi! I'm a div!
      </div>
      <div>
        Hello! I'm another div!
      </div>
      <div>
        And I'm the last div!
      </div>
      <button on-tap="runAnimation">Click me!</button>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          behaviors: [
            Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
          ],
          properties: {
            animationConfig: {
              value: function() { return {
                'entry': {
                  // Leave empty
                }
              } }
            }
          },
    ready: function() {
      var divsNL = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('div');
   var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(divsNL);
   var output = [];
   divs.forEach(function(item) {
     output.push({
                name: 'fade-in-animation',
           node: item,
             timing: { duration: 1000 }
              });
   });
   this.set('animationConfig.entry', output);
    },
          runAnimation: function() {
            this.playAnimation('entry')
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <x-foo></x-foo>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for your reply.  I tried your code, and it does animate the multiple elements, but only ALMOST simultaneously.  There is still a perceptible delay between the animations of each element and the next/adjacent one, even when 'nodeDelay' above is set to 0.  So this does have a cascaded effect, like a chain reaction of animations, but not exactly the simultaneous one that I'm looking for.  I wonder if there's something like 'simultaneous-animation' (vs cascaded-animation) out there...

Comment: I didn't hear anything about that kind of animation but I've got an idea, I'll edit this post later today with another demo